# How to horizontally center image in div while horizontally centering the div on the page?

Tags: html, css

Here is what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jazzepi/6Tgqs/

```
<a class ="banner" href="#">
    <img src="http://www.hettahuskies.com/images/headers/HHwebsite03.jpg">
</a>

.banner {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The layout LOOKS correct, but the image tag is centering itself inside of the anchor div by adding margin to either side. This expands the anchor tag's horizontal size, and clickable area, to the width of the whole page.

I saw another approach that uses display:table-cell; on the containing div (the anchor in this case) and but then I can't use the margin: 0 auto; trick to center the containing div.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jazzepi/6Tgqs/1/

```
<a class ="banner" href="#">
    <img src="http://www.hettahuskies.com/images/headers/HHwebsite03.jpg">
</a>

.banner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
}
```

My goal is to make the anchor div be centered in the page, and it's clickable area to be set to the size of the image. I think my primary problem is that the img nested inside of the anchor doesn't give the anchor tag any width. If I do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jazzepi/6Tgqs/3/

```
<a class ="banner" href="#">
    <img src="http://www.hettahuskies.com/images/headers/HHwebsite03.jpg">
</a>

.banner {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
img {
}
```

It works! But **I don't want to have to specify the width of the image inside of the anchor tag**. The page already has this information!

EDIT - This last link "works" but I'm DO NOT want the width:1000px; in the anchor div. If I change the image later, which might have a different width, I'd then have to change the width of the anchor tag. I'd like the anchor tag to encompass the img without any human intervention.

EDIT - Talking about horizontally centering stuff. Not vertically.

Comment: just check this way: http://jsfiddle.net/6Tgqs/8/

Comment: @Abudayah That technique still requires that I have an image (which already has some width), and then I have to recopy that image width into the CSS and keep the two in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an extra wrapper around your current markup you can do this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/6Tgqs/10/)**

```
<div class="container">
<a class ="banner" href="#">
    <img src="http://www.hettahuskies.com/images/headers/HHwebsite03.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container
{
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
}
.banner {
    display:inline-block;

}
img {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: @Hushme, I think the asker wants **Horizontal** centering not vertical centering

Comment: he can use text-align:center to center image he said he want image in center of body

Comment: I really hate wrapping stuff in semantically meaningless divs, but this looks like the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to make it with display table-cell then here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Tgqs/12/)

Just wrap your anchor with a div then apply height 100% by defining `display: table;`

```
.banner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    display: table;
}
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: if you want horizontally only remove height: 100% from html,body